# Should "Is Docker right for my use case?" stay open?

Tags: discussion, questions, opinion-based

The question I'm wondering about is [this one](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/1179/13).

At first my feeling was that it was a real life practical case where there should be mostly 2 options, Yes or No, and actionnable points to back up the positio. As such the question is on-topic I think.

It appears it attract mostly opinions without anything to back them up; no experienced cases with one or the other technology, most answers omit the question is about an app AND a bunch of services around on a PHYSICAL machine (may or may not be mandatory, but that's a clarification to ask, not an assumption to make, or both possibilities could be addressed, but dismissing the physical box existence to prove your point is not a valid option IMHO).

At time of writing, none of the 5 answers did address the second point (maybe Michael's one does to a certain extent, but that's highly unclear) and none did address the physical part of the problem.

The question author never reacted to any answer and didn't visit the site since the day after asking (May 17th).

I'm tempted to close this question as primarily opinion based as, despite being highly up-voted, it tends to attract nothing more than 'I think this is the way to go but can't give any reason or exemple applying to your case'.

What is the community feeling about this question ?

- It should be closed as time has proven nothing really helpful came from it.
- I (Tensibai) am plain wrong and a such should refrain to comment/janitor this specific question.

Both option are very valid and I'm fully open to ear I'm wrong.

Comment: Something to think about: is the question problematic, or are the answers just missing the mark? If the answers are the problem, then I guess the question shouldn't suffer for it.

Comment: @Aurora0001 Nice point. Didn't though about it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a while leaving this question open and no more feedback than the other answer here at time of writing, I'm tempted to get on the line of Aurora where this question has merit and never found someone to answer it properly.

Overall the community of this site doesn't share my feeling the actual answers miss the mark as they are not down voted so I'll end up leaving similar questions open.

If someone feel this isn't the proper approach, please open another discution post referring to this one if needed, I really think we need to refine our on-topic page, but the lack of feedback doesn't sounds like it's something to open for now.

Answer (score 1):

I am the one that raised flag on that question and I believe that this should be closed.

Currently I have feeling that SE DevOps is flooded with questions about recommendations and too vague to answer otherwise than opinion based. I know it is young community and we do not have many users with closing permissions, but if that doesn't change then I believe SE will close this community as non constructive.

Comment: With around 3 questions per day, talking about a flood is exaggerated. Concerning the site closure see [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/287976), as long as there's no spam posts filling the site, there's no worry to have about a closure. I'd also like more focused questions, but as long as the actual questions doesn't bring a problem of flood, I'd stay on a case by case basis, hence this Meta question about this specific one.

Comment: I am probably one who has asked several questions leading to possibly opinionated answers. Frankly, I would prefer the site to allow that, with the risk of no good answers staying with the poster, obviously. Heck, in the DevOps world, the "evangelist" is a proper job description. While there are certainly many technical questions, the more strategic setup of a devops solution has a a *lot* of impact as well. And picking the correct tool (out of a bunch of similar tools, all building on the same set of base tools/concepts..) isn't really clear of a beginner, no matter how much research is done.